# Adapter methods are not called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've a a recyclerview inside a fragment. The list is displayed empty. Tried to log Adapter methods (onCreateViewHolder and on onBindViewHolder) and it turns out they are not called!

I know that they mostly won't call because getItemCount returns 0. But I've the following check in getItemCount to return list's size only when it's not null && it's size is greater than 0. And btw, the list in the fragment is not empty.

Adapter code:

```
public class SearchOfflineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Question> mSearchList;

    @Inject
    public SearchOfflineAdapter() {
        mSearchList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // Set questions list
    public void setSearchOfflineList(List<Question> searchList) {
        mSearchList = searchList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Timber.d("iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","onCreateViewHolder");
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.item_search_entries, parent, false);
        SearchEntriesViewHolder    searchEntriesViewHolder = new SearchEntriesViewHolder(itemView);
        return searchEntriesViewHolder;


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Timber.d("iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii","onBindViewHolder");

        ((SearchEntriesViewHolder) holder).setItemData(mSearchList.get(position), holder);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("getITemCount hhhh", "===");

        return ( mSearchList!= null && mSearchList.size() > 0) ? mSearchList.size() : -1;

    }

    class SearchEntriesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.text_view_search_entry_title)
        TextView tvSearchEntryTitle;
        @Bind(R.id.edit_text_search_entry)
        EditText txtSearchEntry;

        public SearchEntriesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        public void setItemData(Question question, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            tvSearchEntryTitle.setText(question.getQas());

        }
    }
}
```

Setting adapter to recyclerview snippet:

```
mSearchEntriesAdapter.setSearchOfflineList(questionList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mSearchEntriesAdapter);
```

Comment: first of all post your relevant code here.

Comment: A man should see some code first.

Comment: @Ironman It's logic, no need to post anything. And btw, gettemCount is not called also.

Comment: Are you sure you call setLayoutManager and setAdapter methods on your RecyclerView?

Comment: @Orlangure Yes. Here is the snippet of code responsible about that:

searchOfflineAdapter.setSearchOfflineList(questionList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(searchOfflineAdapter);

Comment: Post your code in the question, please. The solution is somewhere in there.

Comment: @Orlangure I've posted the code above.

Comment: This might not be the cause of your bug, but in your question, you're saying getItemCount returns 0. Looking at your code that should be impossible. Are you sure mSeachlist.size() > 0 shouldn't be >= 0?

Comment: @BadIdeaException  Thanks. I've figured out what the problem was. It was something in arrangement of code.